# SDL/OpenGL error code 0x76FBF489

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, codeblocks

I just created window with sdl and draw with Opengl. I using Code::Blocks. Today i must edit my libraris in Migngw. After that my program just exit and return:

```
Process returned 1996223625 (0x76FBF489)   execution time : 0.001 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I'll try that:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    cout << "Run" << endl;
    ...
}
```

And it shows nothing just return value.

Debugger only says:

```
Error creating process C:/.../bin/Debug/ss.exe, (error 193).
```

Debugger finished with status 0

**I'm sorry I've solved it... It's gcc's error... It doesn't like whitespaces in search paths**.

I hope that will help someone.